# How to fix "BOTTOM OVERFLOWED XXX" without scroll -related widgets

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to locate each widgets across the height of the screen without scroll widget (It means the total height of screen is always fixed), but do not know to implement those widget generally.

For example, height of Iphone 13 is 2532 pixel but 13 pro max is 2778.
If total height of screen is fixed (non allowed to scroll), all widgets should be more shorten (like 70%-80%)than former for pro max.

Should I use MediaQuery class or other responsive libraries generally?

Comment: please add your ui design and code

Comment: Thanks for your comment, and I hope I could show those code but those codes are falling apart in many `.dart` files. Can I easily copy those integrated codes by using DevTools in web browser or something ? I'm really new about VScode and flutter as well, thanks for your kindness.

Answer (score 0):

Making the size of height of a button dynamic is not recommended. You can check telegram signup button the height will stay but the width will be dynamic and reduced x pixel from left or right using margin.

if you are trying to make a floating button like whatsapp which is no matter size of the screen the height and width will stay, you can customize it on floatingactionbutton()

but if you still want to customize the height you can use this logic:

```
var heightOfMyPhone = (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height);
InkWell(
  onTap: (){
  //code here
  },
  child: Container(
    height: heightOfMyPhone > 300 ? (heightOfMyPhone*0.5) : 100,
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    padding:const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
  )),
```